# Dynamically generated button remove by onClick in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client

I have inserted button by onclick in a way that if you click on the button then it will append within `<div id="article-tags"></div>` just like the below image,

[image]

To create that, I have arranged the HTML code segment below:

```
<div id="article-tags">
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button" data-id="1" data-name="tag" class="tag-item">tag</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="2" data-name="tag2" class="tag-item"> tag2</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="3" data-name="tag3" class="tag-item">tag3</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="4" data-name="tag4" class="tag-item">tag4</button>  
</div>
```

And the jQuery code segment is below,

```
$(".tag-item").click(function(){
  var btnid = $(this).data("id");
  var btnname = $(this).data("name");
  $("#article-tags").append("<button type='button' class='tag-selected ntdelbutton'>"+ btnname +" &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-times-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>");
  $(this).css({"background-color": "#DFE2E5", "color": "#ababab"});
  $(this).attr("disabled", true);
  return false;
});
```

But right now, I would like to remove the button by onClick that is populated within

```
<div id="article-tags"></div>
```

I have tried to by using the following jQuery code segment below:

```
$(".tag-selected").click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

or

```
$(".tag-selected").live("click", function() {
      $(this).remove();   
    });
```

But neither is working. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code. Do you want to restore `'disabled': false` attribute after removing specified element?

```js
$(".tag-item").click(function() {
  var btnid = $(this).data("id");
  var btnname = $(this).data("name");
  $("#article-tags").append("<button type='button' class='tag-selected ntdelbutton'>" + btnname + " &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-times-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>");
  $(this).css({
    "background-color": "#DFE2E5",
    "color": "#ababab"
  });
  $(this).attr("disabled", true);
  $(".ntdelbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article-tags">
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button" data-id="1" data-name="tag" class="tag-item">tag</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="2" data-name="tag2" class="tag-item"> tag2</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="3" data-name="tag3" class="tag-item">tag3</button>
  <button type="button" data-id="4" data-name="tag4" class="tag-item">tag4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using plain javascript (rather than the jQuery library) and a dash of CSS:

```js
var upperButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.upper button');
var lowerButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.lower button');

for (let i = 0; i < lowerButtons.length; i++) {
    lowerButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){upperButtons[i].style.visibility = 'visible'; lowerButtons[i].setAttribute('disabled','disabled');}, false);
}

for (let i = 0; i < upperButtons.length; i++) {
    upperButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){upperButtons[i].removeAttribute('style'); lowerButtons[i].removeAttribute('disabled');}, false);
}
```

```css
.upper button {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">
<button type="button">tag</button>
<button type="button">tag2</button>
<button type="button">tag3</button>
<button type="button">tag4</button> 
</div>

<div class="lower">
<button type="button">tag</button>
<button type="button">tag2</button>
<button type="button">tag3</button>
<button type="button">tag4</button>  
</div>
```